# erlang: ending a process without knowing PiD?

Tags: process, erlang, terminate

Simply put; how can I end a process if I accidentally forgot to equate a Pid variable when I started a process using this:

```
9> trivial_process:start().
<0.67.0>
10>
```

I know I should have written `Pid = trivial_process:start().` Is there some way to take <0.67.0> and terminate the process?

```
-module(trivial_process).
-export([start/0]).

start() -> 
  spawn(fun() -> loop() end).

loop() ->
  receive
    Any ->
      io:format("~nI got the message: ~p~n",[Any]),
      loop()
  end.
```

EDIT:Answer.

```
8> Pid = "<0.67.0>".
9> A2 = list_to_pid(Pid).
<0.67.0>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `list_to_pid` function.  The docs are [here](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_pid-1).  You shouldn't use this in deployed code, it's only useful for debugging.  It doesn't work with remote pids, either.

Reference: [Something maybe you don’t know about Erlang PIDs](http://pdincau.wordpress.com/tag/pid/)

Comment: Could you please give an example. I tried this `Pid2 = list_to_pid("<0.67.0>").` with no luck...

Comment: Ok nevermind, just saw your reference where step 8-9 show it. ok